# Yii2 ArrayHelper extract

Tags: массивы, yii2

В Kohana была удобная функция извлечения из массива только определенных колонок https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Arr#extract

Есть что-то подобное в Yii2?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего нужен: [ArrayHelper::getValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html)

```
$array = [
    'foo' => [
        'bar' => new User(),
    ]
];

$value = ArrayHelper::getValue($array, 'foo.bar.name');
```

или `getColumn` (не совсем понял по докам kohana что именно нужно)

```
$array = [
    ['id' => '123', 'data' => 'abc'],
    ['id' => '345', 'data' => 'def'],
];

$ids = ArrayHelper::getColumn($array, 'id');
```

Если нужно выбрать несколько колонок, то наверное придется воспользоваться `callback` функцией. Например:

```
$array = [
            ['id' => '123', 'data' => 'abc', 'hello' => 66, 'test' => 1],
            ['id' => '345', 'data' => 'def', 'hello' => 77, 'test' => 2],
        ];

$result = ArrayHelper::getColumn($array, function ($element) {
    return ['id' => $element['id'], 'data' => $element['data']];
});

// содержание массива $result:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [data] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 345
            [data] => def
        )
)
```

Comment: Из базы поступают данные с 30-ю полями, а мне нужно получить новый массив, состоящий только из полей [field1, field5, field7], т.е. из полного массива извлечь часть полей.

Comment: @VladimirGorobets видимо только через `callback`. Добавил в ответ...... А почему из БД нельзя только их вытащить сразу?